# Command failed: dyld[23446]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libidn2/lib/libidn2.0.dylib

Tags: terminal, mac, homebrew

When I tried to using this [curl_chrome100](https://github.com/lwthiker/curl-impersonate/releases/tag/v0.5.4) command to download html in macOS 13.2 terminal:

```
./curl_chrome100 https://google.com
```

shows error:

```
> ./curl_chrome100 https://google.com
dyld[28254]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libidn2/lib/libidn2.0.dylib
  Referenced from: <8518477D-3A94-30FA-9595-0A10951489A2> /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Downloads/curl-impersonate-v0.5.4.x86_64-macos/curl-impersonate-chrome
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libidn2/lib/libidn2.0.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/opt/libidn2/lib/libidn2.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/opt/libidn2/lib/libidn2.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libidn2.0.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libidn2.0.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
./curl_chrome100: line 26: 28254 Abort trap: 6           "$dir/curl-impersonate-chrome" --ciphers TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256,ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384,ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305,ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305,ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA,AES128-GCM-SHA256,AES256-GCM-SHA384,AES128-SHA,AES256-SHA -H 'sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="100", "Google Chrome";v="100"' -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/100.0.4896.75 Safari/537.36' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: document' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9' --http2 --false-start --compressed --tlsv1.2 --no-npn --alps --cert-compression brotli "$@"
```

I have already installed `libidn`, am I missing something?

```
> brew install libidn
fatal: not in a git directory
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services, skipping update!
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
Warning: libidn 1.41 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 1.41, run:
  brew reinstall libidn
```

the libidn2 already installed:

```
> brew install libidn2
fatal: not in a git directory
Warning: No remote 'origin' in /opt/homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services, skipping update!
Running `brew update --auto-update`...
Warning: libidn2 2.3.4_1 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 2.3.4_1, run:
  brew reinstall libidn2
```

I have tried to add the config into `~/.zshrc`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/libidn2/2.3.4_1/lib/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

still could not fixed this issue.